# Are creatures under the effect of the Minimus Containment version of the Imprisonment spell frozen in place?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

The spell says nothing can pass through the gem except light. Does that include the imprisoned creature moving around the inside of the gem?

Answer (score 5):

### The creature can move within the gem

The spell does not mention anything about the creature being frozen or being unable to move, so it [does not do that to the creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), as presented in detail in [Darth Pseudonym's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195968/are-creatures-under-the-effect-of-the-minimus-containment-version-of-the-impriso/195975#195975) here.

As additional evidence, see this Magic: the Gathering Card, created in consultation with the D&D creative team by the same company that publishes D&D, Wizards of the Coast (from the *Adventures in the Forgotten Realms* set):

[image: Creature in Minimus Containment]

The creature clearly is distressed by its unhappy circumstances, and it pounding and pressing against the prison wall to get out, so it is moving and not frozen in space.

Comment: I'm not sure most people will count that as evidence (for one, that's totally a pose the creature could be caught in). MTG cards are probably quite non-canonical, though I should check if that's true.

Comment: My take here is that this is a "for what it's worth..." piece of *secondary* evidence, and Darth Pseudonym's answer provides a good, detailed analysis of the primary evidence we would be looking for with this question. My recommendation would be to link to Darth's answer specifically, rather than to the generic "spells do what they say they do" Q&A, acknowledging that Darth has provided the primary evidence in their answer, and that this answer is supplemental to that. I'm not downvoting because this *is* useful info, but reframing as I've described would be worth my upvote. Up to you.

Comment: Hi @Phoenices. You're likely right. You can make the plain "Spell does not mention it so, no." argument, I added that. Do only the core rules count as evdidence of how things are supposed to work? I'd think evidence from other sources can help too. This is after all by the same guys that print D&D. Its also a rare opportunity to have visual answer for the question, rather than a purely rule-mechanical one.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMarkov, yes totally right, I updated to refer to Darth (who anyways is the top rated answer). I find it confusing to have a link to the answer, as if it went somewhere else, so I rather kept the link on explaining the principle, but mentioned his answer explicitly.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin In [this meta answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11277/62294) I talk about evidence and how it is viewed by the reader. TL;DR, there is no "official" hierarchy of evidence on the stack, rather readers vote according to their own standards of evidence. Generally, official sources, meaning published sourcebooks, are viewed as the "most authoritative" evidence, but there is still value in other sources, but your mileage may vary with such sources much more than it would with reference to published sourcebook material.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin The advantage of linking to another answer here is that I can click it and go straight there instead of scrolling around looking for the user card with Darth's name in it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's not good evidence; I'm not going to make a judgement on that, even on whether it convinces me. I'm only saying that I believe most people won't think this is evidence.

Answer (score 4):

### Spells only do what they say they do.

While that general concept *can* be applied too harshly, the spell text is usually pretty specific about any game effects.

The containment options given for *imprisonment* are pretty clear about what they do. In general, "the creature doesn't need to breathe, eat, or drink, and it doesn't age", but nothing there says the spell generally keeps the target unconscious or paralyzed.

**Burial** has the target "entombed" (which is not a game term) but otherwise makes no claim about the target being unconscious or paralyzed. **Chaining** causes the *restrained* condition and prevents escape, but that's all. **Slumber** causes the target to fall asleep, which is the *unconscious* condition.

Since **Minimus Containment** doesn't say the target is restrained, paralyzed, unconscious, asleep, petrified, or otherwise incapacitated, there's no reason to think they are. The target is just tiny and trapped inside a gemstone. In this context, "nothing can pass through the gem" should probably be read as meaning the surface of the gemstone, not saying the person inside is embedded in the gem like a fly in amber. If that were the case, I would expect it to say so.

Comment: The spell also doesn't say that the interior of the gemstone becomes anything other than the solid rock that it previously was.

Comment: If it were entombing the target in solid crystal, it would say so, just like the Burial option does. That reading is what I meant by applying the concept too harshly. The spell doesn't need to specify every minute detail of its function, but if it were inflicting anything on the target, it would need to say so.

Comment: It says the target is imprisoned in a crystal, and nowhere does it says the crystal is no longer solid.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, same as Forcecage

Yep, it can! Other spells reference passing through. For instance, [Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage):

> A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side, creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through it and blocking any spells cast into or out from the area.

The fact that Forcecage stops people from passing through doesn't mean they can't move inside it! In the same way, [Antilife Shell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antilife-shell) says

> The barrier prevents an affected creature from passing or reaching through. An affected creature can cast spells or make attacks with ranged or reach weapons through the barrier.

And yet, a living creature can easily move around inside and out of it, it just can't *go through.* Tiny hut, too, that most essential of protections, says creatures can't pass through but doesn't restrict the creatures inside it.

### But, it's also a gem

It looks like it's intended for the creature to be able to move, because it's cool for a princess imprisoned by an evil wizard to be screaming for help and banging on the gem's walls (see Groody's answer). On the other hand, it's your DM's call. It's a solid gem; the spell doesn't explain how you end up inside the gem, and it doesn't explicitly say that the inside of the gem is hollowed out. If your DM says the spell makes the target trapped in there, only able to see, stuck in an expression of fear and horror for all time... that's fine and plausible.

Comment: The problem with your analogy is that forcecage is hollow inside, while gems usually aren't. If the entire inside of the forcecage was composed of the same solid barrier as the exterior is than you would probably be stuck motionless inside it. Such is the case with the gemstone.

Comment: @Cellheim I'd say your argument proves too much: at least _some_ part of the gem must be hollowed out by the spell to make room for the creature's body. The spell doesn't say the creature itself turns into gem material. Because the spell is entirely silent as to how any of this happens, it's necessarily a DM call as to whether the spell hollows out only enough for the body (leaving the creature frozen in place) or more than enough (leaving the creature able to move).